# Neighbor of 10 wrong answer?

Tags: python-3.7

I am getting wrong answer to the following problem:

Given a non-negative number n, print True if n is within 2 of a multiple of 10,  else print false.  For example 22 is within 2 of a multiple of 10 (the multiple here is 20) and 23 is not within 2 of a multiple of 10 (it is within 3 of multiple 20).

Do you see anything wrong? Because certainly I do not.

This is my code:

```
closest_multiple = round(num/10)*10
return (abs(closest_multiple - num) <= 2)
```

Comment: What's the limit (maximum value) of `num` in the problem?

Comment: 3 <= num <= 10^18

Comment: Your code will be wrong with `10**18-10`. Now I hope you can debug it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of  @user202729, the answer is:

apparently it has to do with the accuracy of the floating point representation, which applies to most languages. Perhaps is not that good to work with fp numbers then in this case... 9999999999999999.0 in fp64 would be 10000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

```
#(10-a) will check for numbers consisting of unit digits as 8 and 0
#(a) will check for numbers consisting of unit digits as 0, 1 and 2

def isNeighbour(num):
    if num >= 3:
        a = num % 10
        if (10-a)<=2 or a<=2:
            print("Is Neighbour")
            return True
        else:
            print("Not neighbour")
            return False
    else:
        print("Not neighbour")
        return False
```

Comment: Maybe there is something really subtle about Python that I'm missing here ... but how is `(10-(10-a))` any different from `a`?